# xcode git unable to pull changes from the remote repository

Tags: xcode, git

I'm developing an iPhone application with another developer. Our git repository is situated on the remote server.

So we are working with our working copies and then we do commit, pull, push one by one and we get our local working copies synchronized with server and with each other.

Everything worked fine until this day. Other developer successfully pushed his changes to the remote repository, and now it is my turn: commit, pull changes from the remote repository, maybe merge them somehow and then push my working copy to the server.

But when I'm trying to pull changes (using xcode's built-in git) I'm getting an error:
**"The operation could not be performed because "%reponame%" has one or more tree conflicts"**.

Please, guide me through the process of solving this problem. And, please, provide useful tips to avoid this problem in future.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess xcode uses option to force fast-forward merges when pulling from repository. That is not bad idea, becouse it prevents you from undesired merges.

Try to use `git pull --rebase` (resp. check some appropriate checkbox in xcode), it should remove your changes, download new version and then apply your removed changes back. Conflict will occur at the last step so you will solve it and commit that changes again. Then you can push them on server.

Comment: Perfect.. You save my valuable time