# Resolving SVN tree conflicts in Xcode

Tags: xcode, svn, merge, xcode5, tree-conflict

I'm trying to resolve a tree conflict from SVN in Xcode. From the answer here [The operation could not be performed because "PROJECTNAME" has one or more tree conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356528/the-operation-could-not-be-performed-because-projectname-has-one-or-more-tree) I should simply resolve the conflict using the command-line. No problem, I've got some experience with SVN command line, so I do exactly that

```
svn merge ^/project/trunk
svn resolve --accept working conflictedFile1.m
svn resolve --accept working conflictedFile2.m
svn resolve --accept working conflictedFile3.m
svn ci . -m "merge: from trunk"
```

Then I go back to Xcode and just to make sure everything is happy and try to test that everything "took". I do "Source Control -> Update" and then "Source Control -> project -> Merge from Branch … -> trunk" and I again get the stupid error message: "The operation could not be performed because of one or more tree conflicts." and the additional message "The files conflictedFile1.m, conflictedFile2.m, and conflictedFile3.m had a tree conflict."

In fact my question is not how to resolve this tree conflict, but how do I tell Xcode that I already did resolve the conflict? Is there some out-of-date svn database somewhere that I need to refresh/delete? Did I resolve this wrong in the first place?

Bonus question:

It would be really nice to continue to use Xcode's builtin SVN features to do merges, etc. I can use the command line but I'd really rather not for things like merges, when I have a builtin merge-diff tool in my IDE. In general, any advice on using SVN in Xcode properly is greatly appreciated. Therefore, if there is any specific advice anybody can give me to prevent this from happening in the future, I'll be very happy.

What I did was:
(1) branch from trunk to Branch1
(2) add a file on Branch1 (as well as other edits)
(3) branch from Branch1 to Branch2
(4) make edits (no new files)
(5) merge from Branch2 to trunk
(6) merge from trunk to Branch1 -> tree conflict with the files originally created here

Comment: **Bonus Question**- will answering this will fetch 20 points?

Comment: This is frustrating - I jumped over to my PC and using tortoise SVN it merged just fine.

Comment: It is annoying. I had no problem resolving the conflict command-line, but my Xcode still thinks something is broken. @WayneUroda Did resolving in tortoise fix anything for you?

Comment: @xaviersjs no xcode is still broken - I've been busy on another project and haven't completed the full merge back into my trunk - if it is still broken I will probably delete the local copy and get it fresh out of SVN, and if it is broken still then I will grep for the files it is complaining about inside the xc files to see if they are recorded there