# Xcode merge branch,remind tree conflict when add some new file

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I create a branch2 and add some new class file,when i merge into master branch,Xcode reminds us:**"The files ViewModel.h,ViewModel.m had a tree conflict"**
If I just edit some code but not add new file,it will be ok,but how should i solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16369770/2399980

Answer (score 8):

Change to your master branch, and then use the option "Merge from branch", and select your branch2.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. The problem was that the `master` branch had uncommited changes (unrelated to the changes in the other one). Switching to `master` and committing the changes allowed me to merge the feature branch back into `master`.