# Tree conflict on projectname.entitlements

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

In XCode, I'm trying to merge from another branch, but I get an error:

*"The operation could not be performed because of one or more tree conflicts. The file [projectname].entitlements had a tree conflict."*

I heard that this refers to conflicts in the file structure in the XCode project file, but both the entitlements file and its path seem identical in both branches.

According to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16369770) instructions tried to pull from the branch, but nothing seems to change and I still keep getting the error. What causes this and how can I fix it?